# Decreasing function on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Originally my problem is to prove that

> If $n>945$ then ${(\frac{6.5}{\sqrt {27}})}^{n} > {3n}^{\sqrt {3n}/{2}}  $ where $n$ is a natural number.

And I arrived in the situation that I have to show that $\frac{\ln(3x)}{\sqrt x}$ is a decreasing function. I used the existing theorem:

> Let the function $f$ be continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ if $f'(x) < 0$.

However, I got confused if my proof is correct since I don't know if the domain $ (0, \infty)$ or only in $(945, \infty)$.

If I use $(945, \infty)$, my critical point is $0.04511$ which is not an element of the domain. If  $ (0, \infty)$, the graph is not really decreasing in $(0,1]$.

Comment: what you call "theorem" is just an assertion.

Comment: If a function defined on some $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ is increasing (resp. decreasing) on $D$, then it is increasing (resp. decreasing) on any $S \subset D$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{\log (3 x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ has a derivative

$f'(x)=\dfrac{2-\log (3 x)}{2 x^{3/2}}$

which is positive in $\left(0,\;\dfrac{e^2}{3}\right)$ and negative for $x>\dfrac{e^2}{3}$

About the original problem of proving that
$$\left(\frac{6.5}{\sqrt{27}}\right)^n>3 n^{\frac{\sqrt{3 n}}{2}},\text{ for } n>945$$
I found a weird jump from $n=622$ to $n=623$

for $n=622$ you have $2.82\times 10^{61},\;2.84\times 10^{61}$ for LHS and RHS while at $n=623$ they become $3.52\times 10^{61}, 3.28\times 10^{61}$

thus the inequality holds  for $n>622$

Hope this helps

Comment: @Rafaelle. Actually I get $f'(x)= \frac{2+ln(3x)}{2{x^{3/2}}}$. Is it the same thing?

Comment: @jENEVA Quotient rule $\dfrac{\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}}-\dfrac{\log (3 x)}{2 \sqrt{x}}}{x}$

Comment: oK. i get it now. Instead of subtraction, I write addition. Thanks